# Testing websites locally with the original URL?

Tags: networking, proxy, ssl, virtual-host

We're a team of web developers, we have local versions of our clients' websites and we want to test them locally before uploading.

In order to run the websites with their original URL, we decided to set up a proxy server that'll load the sites from a local computer that has xampp installed on with virtual hosts - which we'll connect our browsers to.

The proxy we created was made in nodejs using the node-http-proxy module,
the only problem we're now having is websites that are using SSL.

Even though we set our browser's SSL proxy to go through our nodejs proxy - no requests were obtained.

I'd love to know if there's a better way to achieve this functionality, or if you have any ideas for why the SSL requests didn't even reach the proxy server.

*Just some random technical stuff:*

- Port 8000 was used
- The proxy listened to all requests and 'console.log'ged once any request was made.
- When going directly to the proxy server like so: '127.0.0.1:8000' (without setting it as a proxy in the browser) the proxy server did get the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use different DNS (or the `hosts` file) to override the FQDN to your test server IP.

Either do it locally on your machines (on Windows its in `\Windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts` file), or continue to use your nodejs proxy, but on the proxy server don't do anything fancy and just override the FQDN in DNS. Then also SSL requests will work via that proxy.

Comment: Do you know of a way to do that without setting the hosts manually on every machine? the proxy allowed us to redirect all requests through it and basically allowed us to have one browser dedicated to QA and the other for normal browsing - but I don't know how to achieve that with nodejs or if it's possible at all

Comment: As mentioned in the answer - dedicate one host to the nodejs proxy and change the DNS / hosts file only on that host

Comment: Not the best way really as I wouldn't want to dedicate a computer for that purpose only, but it works so I'll give you that :) thank you buddy